# Use in-app for trial?

Tags: mac-appstore

I was wondering if I could offer (paid) trials of my App in the Mac Appstore using in-app purchase?

So I have a $49 value Mac app, but I allow downloading for free, the app needs a $1.99 in-app purchase to activate the trial for a month.

Do you think it would work. Would Apple allow it?

Answer (score 3):

> Apps that are “beta”, “demo”, “trial”, or “test” versions will be rejected
>
> Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected, except in cases where the application hosts plug-ins or extensions
>
> Apps containing “rental” content or services that expire after a limited time will be rejected

Doesn't seem like it's allowed.

**Source:** [App Store Review Guidelines for iOS apps (login required)](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to have trial anything on the app store. Your free app needs to be fully functional.

You can do paid subscriptions in a free app however.